# String to JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Ajax call gets `"[['Best Value (62)',62 ],['LPTA (32)',32 ],] "` as the return value. I need to pass this as an array. Is there a way to make the string into an array without resorting to `eval()`?

Comment: If you really have that trailing comma, not even eval() will save you.

Comment: why you have a result like that, instead of a properly json-encoded array?

Comment: @Brian: Trailing commata are valid in array literals?

Comment: @Bergi trailing commas kill almost all versions of IE, so I wouldn't count on it

Comment: @Brian: I thought the question was about JavaScript, not jscript :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get rid of the trailing comma and change the double quotes to escaped double quotes  and anything else you have in the array is well formed then you can use JSON.parse to turn the string into an array. If you have access to the serverside code you'll likely want to make the changes there rather than in your js.

```
JSON.parse("[[\"Best Value (62)\",62],[\"LPTA (32)\",32]]")
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON, either (single quotes)

Comment: Removed trailing comma, changed single quotes to double, and there we go! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you have isn't JSON, but is valid JavaScript (assuming the extra comma was a copy-paste error). And, as much as I dislike it, you can use eval:

```
// convert the input in to a javascript array
var o = eval("[['Best Value (62)',62],['LPTA (32)',32]]");
// use jQuery map to grab only the first array value and return
// each selection back as an array
$.map(o, function(a){
  return a[0];
}); // ['Best Value (62)','LPTA (32)'];
```

if the extra comma is there to stay, you can use a little more processing to get rid of it:

```
var data = "[['Best Value (62)',62],['LPTA (32)',32],]";
var o = eval(data.replace(/\],\]$/,']]'));
$.map(o, function(a){
  return a[0];
});
```

Comment: *"...without resorting to `eval()`"*

Comment: there is no "without resorting to eval". it's not JSON, it's not a native object. the only other way to translate it to something you can work with is with eval...

Comment: The extra comma does not make it invalid JS.

Comment: @Bergi Except for IE (< 9 I believe)

Comment: There's always an option--you can parse the string semi-easily without eval. Anyway answering "you can use X" to a question that says "How can I do Y without using X?" isn't a good answer.

Comment: @Juhana: "Is there any way...". yes, however not without a lot of overhead and re-inventing the proverbial wheel. You're right, you could get in to direct string parsing but I doubt OP wants to develop (and test) something that extensive. (maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: I mean, technically you could programmatically replace the quotes and fix the comma then pass it to JSON.parse, but what's the point. fixing the comma and evaling it is much easier.

Comment: @KevinB: I almost went that route but fear the values may have escaped single quotes in them as well (and I'm not about to replace `'` and not expect to see `''` or `\'`).

Comment: Exactly, it gets far more complex if you start replacing quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.parse("[['Best Value (62)',62 ],['LPTA (32)',32 ],]".replace(/(,])$/, ']').replace(/'/g, '"'))
```

Comment: not the dv, but how would you handle single quotes in the middle of the string? now you would end up with a string value like `"doesn"t work",` Unless with the given data the values are set and it isn't possible to have said quotes